Acer Chromebook model CB 315
Okay I have an Acer Chromebook model cb15 now I was able to use a lot of commands to disable write protect and to enable legacy but I am unable to enable USB booting every command I have found online does not work
Any help would be much appreciated for all I want to do is install Linux on the Chromebook so I can play steam games I don't have a lot of money to go out and buy a new laptop and every time I try to get help from somebody they want me to pay $5 for a technician
